# Force perl to use module-version if more are installed

Tags: perl, cpanm

on the server i'm working on perl is installed. I can't change anything on this installation, so i installed cpanm to create my own repository of cpan modules. I defined the install-dir and installed modules there.

The problem is, that some modules are already installed on the server-perl in another version. So i get following error message (this for example, i get this for other modules with other pl-scripts, too)

```
Digest::MD5 object version 2.39 does not match bootstrap parameter 2.53 at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 223.
```

in /usr/lib64/perl5 the server-perl modues are installed. Mine are in another directory.

How can i force perl to use my modules if he finds more versions? And is that even the root of the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The order of the paths in `@INC` matters. Put your directories before the default ones. You can set the environment variable `PERL5LIB` to point to your directory to achieve that.

Comment: i read about that, but i forgot to mention that as soon as PERL5LIB is set the error occurs. Is there a possibility to set my directory to the head of @INC without setting PER5LIB?

Comment: Wait, DynaLoader? It seems there are two different versions of Perl involved.

Comment: @choroba, No, Digest::MD5 is the module that's in `@INC` that shouldn't be

Answer (score 0):

The version can only be determined by executing (loading) the module, so continuing to look for other versions is problematic.

Modules with a binary component are installed in arch dirs (e.g. `.../x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/...`). Installing in an external directory using `INSTALL_BASE` (used by local::lib) also creates architecture-specific libraries. You should not have one Perl installation include the arch dir of another build of Perl. Undo whatever you did to add it. An inappropriate `PERL5LIB`, maybe?

Comment: I installed local::lib and set the directory to `~/lib/perl/cpan/locallib`. I also set the `PERL5LIB` and thought i have to set it to `~/lib/perl/cpan/locallib/lib/perl5`. I f i do so, it automatically adds `~/lib/perl/cpan/locallib/lib/perl5` AND `~/lib/perl/cpan/locallib/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi` to @INC. Which is the right value for `PERL5LIB`? Just the local::lib directory?

Comment: Re "Which is the right value for PERL5LIB?" `~/lib/perl/cpan/locallib` if you only used the `perl` build you are currently using to install modules into that directory. Not `~/lib/perl/cpan/locallib` (e.g. empty) otherwise